# Reading Windows command line arguments in IronPython

Tags: windows, command-line-arguments, ironpython

OK, I found three similar threads but all of them dealt with command-line arguments in C#.  My question is, how can I read the command-line arguments from the cmd window, into IronPython?

The way I read Section 2.1.1 in [these docs](http://ironpython-test.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/interpreter.html), it should work the same as CPython -- just import the `sys` module and get the values from the `sys.argv` array.  It doesn't.  Here's the test code I tried (file z.py):

```
import sys
print sys.argv[0]
print sys.argv[1]
```

When I call this as `z.py testing` using the CPython (2.7.4) interpreter, I get what you'd expect:

```
E:\>c:\python27\python.exe z.py testing
z.py
testing

E:\>
```

But when I call it using the IronPython (2.7.3) interpreter, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\z.py", line 3, in <module>
IndexError: index out of range: 1
```

If I comment out line 3 and try again with IronPython, it runs fine:

```
E:\>z.py testing
E:\z.py

E:\>
```

So `sys.argv[0]` is being assigned but that's it -- the command-line arguments never appear as additional elements in `sys.argv`.

So either there's some extra step I'm missing, or `sys.argv` just doesn't work for this purpose in IronPython.  Either way, how do I get the module to recognize the arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that IronPython installation hasn't registered the python interpreter correctly. It just passes the first argument (which is the script name) to the IronPython interpreter, missing the rest of the arguments. That is: it registered the `*.py` files with `...\ipy.exe %1` instead of `...\ipy.exe %*`.

The solution is to run the scripts with the interpreter directly - as you do with the python.exe:

```
E:\>c:\path\to\ipy64.exe z.py testing
```

And **not** as:

```
E:\>z.py testing
```

*I think this should be reported as a bug on the IronPython installation.*

Comment: That took care of it.  Thanks very much!